# JVM takes the whole XMX memory at startup

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

Edit:

I'm changing my question to make it more clarify.

Here is my app, running with defualt gc in java8:
Yes, there are a lot of gc time, but, my commited memory fits to my actual used memory (I know this is not the desired behabiour)
[image]

Now, lets take a look what happens when we set up G1 gc:
[image]

You can see the commited memory is much much larger than the used one.

You might be wondering what has changed between first and second execution:
The first one goes with JVM_ARGS: `-Xms1024m -Xmx20048m -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=100`

The second one:`-XX:+UseG1GC -Xms1024m -Xmx20048m -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=100 -XX:+UseStringDeduplication`

I've been reading a lot about G1 GC, but, I can't understand why this simple change, makes my memory behabes so diferent?

Comment: *"my process is not consuming more than 1.5GB"* => How do you know?

Comment: Activate the GC log (see for example https://www.baeldung.com/java-gc-logging-to-file) and you will probably see what happens. Most likely the memory is put to use and you would have more frequent/expensive garbage collections with a lower limit.

Comment: Also get a heap dump

Answer (score 0):

As described in [this document from Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E22289_01/html/821-1274/configuring-the-default-jvm-and-java-arguments.html) `-Xmx` sets the maximum available Memory for the jvm and `-Xms` the initial memory, so with your values, the jvm uses 1024mb at stat up and **up to** 4096m when running. So this setting is more a limit then a consumption value.
Compare it to a bucket: If it can hold 10 Liters, you don't have to fill 10 Liters into this bucket, you could also fill it with only 2 Liters

Comment: thanks for your answer. I understand that, how xms and xmx works and all that stuff. However, as you can see in my eddit, my application is not really consumming that memory. I mean, the commited memory is much much higher than the actual used. Is there any reason for that to be happening?

Comment: the commited memory is reserved for the application. So your programm "owns" this much memory, but it doesn't need to use them. Referring to my Bucket example, The 10L Bucket is your commited/reserved memory. You can use that, but you don't need to. You can also only use 2 Liters of these 10 Liters for a liquid. For your application: You gave it more memory, but it doesn't need that much, so it uses less memory.

Comment: I know, but, my xms is 1024 MB, It doesn't make sense for java to commit all these memory, when it's not really needed. So, why is it commiting that much memory?